# Break from underscore loop with lint issues

Tags: javascript, angularjs, underscore.js, jslint, gulp-eslint

Below is the code, trying to break the loop once the result is found by returning true

```
ngModel.$parsers.unshift(function (viewValue) {
                    let names = scope.vm.names;

                    _.find(names, function (elem) {
                        let name = elem.name;

                        if (name && viewValue) {
                            if (name.toLowerCase() === viewValue.toLowerCase()) {
                                ngModel.$setValidity('unique', false);
                                return true; // break out of this loop
                            } else {
                                ngModel.$setValidity('unique', true);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    return viewValue;
                });
```

Code is working absolutely fine as per the expectations, but lint throws error as:

```
 × Unnecessary 'else' after 'return'. (no-else-return)
 27 |                                     ngModel.$setValidity('unique', false);
 28 |                                     return true; // break out of this loop
 29 |                                 } else {
    |                                        ^
 30 |                                     ngModel.$setValidity('unique', true);
 31 |                                 }
 32 |                             }
```

How to suppress this error or is there a way to write better code to get rid off this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve the lint warnings, you can use below code.

```
if (name && viewValue) {
    let equal = name.toLowerCase() === viewValue.toLowerCase();
    ngModel.$setValidity('unique', !equal);
    if (equal) {
        return true; // break out of this loop
    }
}
```

To set the `unique` status, boolean is used and if this is true, then from `if`, `true` is returned.

Comment: Absolutely genius, worked like a charm. Thanks @Tushar